# no response in nodejs while using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

i am trying to convert xml data to json data using async/await in nodejs..
i am getting the data in sqlmapper code, but when i try to link it to the controller code i am not getting response

**sqlmapper code:**

```
 const GetList = async function (Data) {
            try {
                let result = await db.pool.request()
                .input('id', db.sql.Int, Data.id)
                .input('user', db.sql.Int, Data.user)
                    .execute('usp_GetList')
                if (result.recordset) {
                    var resp = result.recordset[0];
                    let value = Object.values(resp)[0];
                    xml2js.parseString(value, { mergeAttrs: true }, (err, jsonresult) => {
                        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonresult);
                        let value1 = myJSON.replace("\"", "");
                        console.log('myJSON', value1);
                        return utill.responseSuccessJSON(200, "success", myJSON);
                    });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                if (error) {
                    return utill.responseErrorJSON(401, "error", error)
                }
            }
        }
```

the above code is the code i placed in sqlmapper.js

**controller code:**

```
const GetList = async(request, response) => {
    let Data = request.body;
    let result =await sqlmapper.GetGroupUserList(Data);
    return response.json(result);
}
```

the above code is the code where i used in my controller in this i am getting result as undefined

```
please help me to get json data which is converted from xml in response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your function `GetList` when you call `xml2js` parser. You are passing the callback to the parse function, and returning a value from a callback. Returning value from callback is not the same as returning a value from the outer function call. The solution is to wrap the function call into a promise and return the promise.

```
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
           xml2js.parseString(value, { mergeAttrs: true }, (err, jsonresult) => {
                    if (err) {
                       return reject(err);
                    }
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonresult);
                    let value1 = myJSON.replace("\"", "");
                    console.log('myJSON', value1);
                    resolve(utill.responseSuccessJSON(200, "success", myJSON));
                });
            }
}
```